# opening a text file on a Macbook

Tags: python

I downloaded a text file on my Macbook, I believe my code is correct and there are no errors in the spelling of the file. This is my code

```py
Mydata=r'/Users/janetnorio/Desktop/CylindricalRollerBearingData_01.txt'
with open(Mydata, 'r') as Datafile:
  Datafile.readline()
  Datafile.readline()
  Units=Datafile.readline().split('\t')
```

and the code prints the following

```sh
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Applications/Python 3.7/Homework assignments and other /Python_project01.py", line 7, in <module>
        Datafile.readline()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
        (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 24: invalid continuation byte
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: What kind of file was this? Was it renamed a `.txt`? You'll need to open this in binary or bytes mode `'rb'`, since `'r'` mode will try to decode the data into a string

Comment: file may use different encoding then `utf-8` - ie. `latin1`, `mac_latin2`, etc. and you may have to use `open(...., encoding=latin1)`. See table with [standard encodings](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)

Comment: BTW: you can try module [chardet](https://github.com/chardet/chardet) to detect charset in file/string

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

There is likely an incorrect usage of the unicode characters inside the file as according to wikipedia, there is info about how certain binary values have to followed by other values Here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Design. I cannot say this for sure, however because I did not get to see the contents of the text file.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mydata=r'/Users/janetnorio/Desktop/CylindricalRollerBearingData_01.txt'
with open(Mydata, 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1") as Datafile:
  Datafile.readline()
  Datafile.readline()
  Units=Datafile.readline().split('\t')
```

I think you should add an encoding argument for open.

Comment: I just guessed it, if it does not work you should use **chardet** to detect the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, can't test the code below in MacOS environment,
but summarizing everyone's answers and comments, your code should look like

```py
import chardet

my_data_filepath = '<my_filepath>'

with open(my_data_filepath, 'rb') as file:
  my_data_encoding = chardet.detect(file.read())['encoding']

if my_data_encoding:
  with open(my_data_filepath, encoding=my_data_encoding) as file:
    file.readline()
    file.readline()
    units = file.readline().split('\t')
else:
  print(f'Encoding is not recognized.')
```